# ElasticSearch => How to updates with a partial document using update_by_query

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to update the data in my index whose cname is wang.
My index code is as follows:

```
PUT index_c
{
   "mappings": {
      "_doc" : {
         "properties" : {
            "cid" : {
               "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "cname" : {
               "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "cage" : {
               "type" : "short"
            },
            "chome" : {
               "type" : "text"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And my update request is as follows:

```
POST index_c/_update_by_query
{
   "query" : {
      "match": {
        "cname": "wang"
      }
   },
   "doc" : {
      "cage" : "100",
      "chome" : "china"
   }
}
```

But I got an error like this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [doc].",
        "line": 1,
        "col": 43
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [doc].",
    "line": 1,
    "col": 43
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

So I want to know how to implement this when using "update_by_query"

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work for you just replace the `doc` part with `script`. if `inline` shows **deprecated** for you then just use `source` instead

```
POST index_c/_update_by_query
{
    "query" : {
      "match": {
        "cname": "wang"
      }
   },
   "script" : {
      "inline" : "ctx._source.cage='100'; ctx._source.chome= 'china';", 
      "lang"   : "painless"
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. But if I want to update 100 fields, I need to write "ctx._source.field=value"  100 times. Is there an easier way when the amount of fields is large?

Comment: @wangjinhao for now I can say Yes you've to write like that 100 times for 100 fields. It should have some sorter way but I don't know at this time. As I used `ctx_source.field=field` for 1 field previously that's why I suggested it to you.